# C# concurrent: Is it a good idea to use many AutoResetEvent?

Tags: c#, concurrency, autoresetevent

Suppose there are many threads calling `Do()`, and only one worker thread handles the actual job.

```
void Do(Job job)
{
    concurrentQueue.Enqueue(job);
    // wait for job done
}

void workerThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Job job;
        if (concurrentQueue.TryDequeue(out job))
        {
            // do job
        }
    }
}
```

The Do() should wait until the job done before return. So I wrote the following code:

```
class Task 
{
    public Job job;
    public AutoResetEvent ev;
}

void Do(Job job)
{
    using (var ev = new AutoResetEvent(false))
    {
        concurrentQueue.Enqueue(new Task { job = job, ev = ev }));
        ev.WaitOne();
    }
}

void workerThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Task task;
        if (concurrentQueue.TryDequeue(out task))
        {
            // do job
            task.ev.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

After some tests I found it works as expected. However I'm not sure is it a good way to allocate many AutoResetEvents, or is there a better way to accomplish?

Comment: By this you're creating multiple OS-level synchronization objects which probably isn't very efficient. As an alternative you can use `TaskCompletionSource` in order to expose the TPL `Task` objects instead of your custom `Task`, which will give possibility to await on completion of job as an extra benefit.

Comment: If `Do` has to wait for the job to complete then why bother running it on a separate worker thread?

Comment: You have only one worker thread so the job will wait anyway...

Comment: Since you use the `WaitOne` only once before disposing the primitive, it doesn't matter if you use `AutoResetEvent` or `ManualResetEvent`. So why not go with [`ManualResetEventSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim) that is more lightweight and efficient?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, thanks for your advice. After ilspy into ManualResetEventSlim, I found that as stated in msdoc "However, if the event does not become signaled within a certain period of time, ManualResetEventSlim resorts to a regular event handle wait." "a certain period of time" is as short as a douzen of for-yield, which is too short for me. So it actually comes to how ManualResetEvent is compared with TaskCompletionSource?

Comment: @Cauly you are right. In your case using `ManualResetEventSlim` won't make much of a difference, because the wait times are expected to be long. It seems that your design is not centered around performance anyway. You may have some particular reason (thread affinity?) to force all jobs done by a specific thread.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes the job deals with a com component that is supposed to be manupated with only one thread.

Comment: Now it makes sense. I'll post an answer using `TaskCompletionSource`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all clients must wait a single thread to do the job, there is no real need for using a queue. So I suggest to use the [`Monitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor) class instead, and specifically the [Wait/Pulse](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Signaling_with_Wait_and_Pulse) functionality. It is a bit low level and verbose though.

```
class Worker<TResult> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly object _outerLock = new object();
    private readonly object _innerLock = new object();
    private Func<TResult> _currentJob;
    private TResult _currentResult;
    private Exception _currentException;
    private bool _disposed;

    public Worker()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(MainLoop);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void MainLoop()
    {
        lock (_innerLock)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(_innerLock); // Wait for client requests
                if (_disposed) break;
                try
                {
                    _currentResult = _currentJob.Invoke();
                    _currentException = null;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _currentException = ex;
                    _currentResult = default;
                }
                Monitor.Pulse(_innerLock); // Notify the waiting client that the job is done
            }
        } // We are done
    }

    public TResult DoWork(Func<TResult> job)
    {
        TResult result;
        Exception exception;
        lock (_outerLock) // Accept only one client at a time
        {
            lock (_innerLock) // Acquire inner lock
            {
                if (_disposed) throw new InvalidOperationException();
                _currentJob = job;
                Monitor.Pulse(_innerLock); // Notify worker thread about the new job
                Monitor.Wait(_innerLock); // Wait for worker thread to process the job
                result = _currentResult;
                exception = _currentException;
                // Clean up
                _currentJob = null;
                _currentResult = default;
                _currentException = null;
            }
        }
        // Throw the exception, if occurred, preserving the stack trace
        if (exception != null) ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(exception).Throw();
        return result;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lock (_outerLock)
        {
            lock (_innerLock)
            {
                _disposed = true;
                Monitor.Pulse(_innerLock); // Notify worker thread to exit loop
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var worker = new Worker<int>();
int result = worker.DoWork(() => 1); // Accepts a function as argument
Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");
worker.Dispose();
```

Output:

```
Result: 1
```

---

**Update:** The previous solution is not await-friendly, so here is one that allows proper awaiting. It uses a `TaskCompletionSource` for each job, stored in a `BlockingCollection`.

```
class Worker<TResult> : IDisposable
{
    private BlockingCollection<TaskCompletionSource<TResult>> _blockingCollection
        = new BlockingCollection<TaskCompletionSource<TResult>>();

    public Worker()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(MainLoop);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void MainLoop()
    {
        foreach (var tcs in _blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            var job = (Func<TResult>)tcs.Task.AsyncState;
            try
            {
                var result = job.Invoke();
                tcs.SetResult(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tcs.TrySetException(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public Task<TResult> DoWorkAsync(Func<TResult> job)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>(job,
            TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
        _blockingCollection.Add(tcs);
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public TResult DoWork(Func<TResult> job) // Synchronous call
    {
        var task = DoWorkAsync(job);
        try { task.Wait(); } catch { } // Swallow the AggregateException
        // Throw the original exception, if occurred, preserving the stack trace
        if (task.IsFaulted) ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(task.Exception.InnerException).Throw();
        return task.Result;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
    }
}
```

Usage example

```
var worker = new Worker<int>();
int result = await worker.DoWorkAsync(() => 1); // Accepts a function as argument
Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");
worker.Dispose();
```

Output:

```
Result: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

From a synchronization perspective this is working fine.

But it seems useless to do it this way. If you want to execute jobs one after the other you can just use a lock:

```
lock (lockObject) {
  RunJob();
}
```

What is your intention with this code?

There also is an efficiency question because each task creates an OS event and waits on it. If you use the more modern `TaskCompletionSource` this will use the same thing under the hood if you synchronously wait on that task. You can use asynchronous waiting (`await myTCS.Task;`) to possibly increase efficiency a bit. Of course this infects the entire call stack with async/await. If this is a fairly low volume operation you won't gain much.

Comment: I can't use lock because RunJob() deals with a com component that is supposed to be manupated with only one thread.

Comment: @Cauly that's a valid reason to do it this way. I'd have no major critique of your code. Maybe it's easier to use a custom TaskScheduler. That way each work items is represented as a Task which composes well. You can wait and await it.

Answer (score 1):

In general I think would work, although when you say "many" threads are calling Do() this might not scale well ... suspended threads use resources.

Another problem with this code is that at idle times, you will have a "hard loop" in "workerThread" which will cause your application to return high CPU utilization times.   You may want to add this code to "workerThread":

```
if (concurrentQueue.IsEmpty) Thread.Sleep(1);
```

You might also want to introduce a timeout to the WaitOne call to avoid a log jam.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, the code in question is simplified for demonstration ^_^